# Firebase RTDB Listener doesn't work with FastAPI

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, fastapi

Here is my code related to Firebase RTDB Listener:

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db


class FirebaseConfig:
    reference = None
    listenerRegistration = None

    def __init__(self):
        cred = credentials.Certificate("path_to_credentials.json")
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(
            cred,
            {'databaseURL': 'database_url'}
        )
        self.reference = db.reference("Users")
        self.listenerRegistration = self.reference.listen(self.userListener)

    def userListener(self, event):
        print("Listener Started.")
        try:
            print(event.data)
            updateData() # A function to update our local database
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception("Listener Error" + str(e))

    def stopListening(self):
        print("Closing Listener")
        self.listenerRegistration.close()
```

The problem I am facing right now is that this listener doesn't work. The print statements don't print anything. I think this is because of FastAPI. Is there any way that I can make it work?

If they cannot work well together, do you have any alternative solutions for the same?

Comment: Where do you call these methods? Can we see the calling code?

Comment: What's the relationship with FastAPI? Does it work without FastAPI? How do you configure this?

Comment: @fchancel, I can share the code. However, the calling of these functions is here only. You can see that I am adding the listener in the class initialization itself. I have created an object for the class before I start my FastAPI code.

Comment: @MatsLindh it actually works after I shut down the FastAPI server. That is why I am having all this trouble. So, after the server shuts down, it prints all the data and stuff. So, I think there is some problem due to FastAPI. If you have any other alternative for the same, I would be open to it.

Comment: How do you set up the listeners and start them? Have you tried moving the Firebase portion out to its own thread? The problem is probably related to uvicorn using its own event loop, and therefor it doesn't cooperate with firebase's eventloop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66275747/how-to-use-event-loop-created-by-uvicorn for a possible solution for uvicorn; check the documentation if something similar is possible for firebase_admin.

Comment: @MatsLindh, I have seen the GitHub repo for firebas_admin. It doesn't have an event loop as such. So, I don't know what the issue might be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might have probably been because I was using port 80 for my uvicorn server. I changed it and it worked.
This is the most probable reason. Cannot say for sure.